# SoapUI change response in REST mock service

Tags: rest, groovy, mocking, soapui

I'm trying to mock a REST service in SoapUI 5.0. I'm using this groovy script in OnRequest tab:

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult mockResult = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)

def httpResponse = mockRequest.httpResponse
httpResponse.setContentType("application/xml;charset=utf-8")
httpResponse.writer << "<root><user>ABC</user></root>"
httpResponse.status = 200
return mockResult
```

And getting this error:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.mock.RestMockRequest)
```

What's wrong? :(

Comment: Damn! It's working in SoapUI 4.6.4 and it is depressing :-D

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! I'm found solution for SoapUI 5!

```
def httpResponse = mockRequest.httpResponse
mockResponse.setResponseHttpStatus(202)
httpResponse.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8")
mockResponse.setResponseContent('{"a": 1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

`WsdlMockResult()` constructor takes `WsdlMockRequest` as an argument.

See [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/mock/WsdlMockResult.html).

Comment: It's funny :) WsdlMockRequest giving me similar error: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(java.lang.Class)

Comment: there is any other way to change the REST response?